# How can I fix my random number generator?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

So I had this random thing setup where you would click a button and a random number 1-50 would show up. For some reason now all of the sudden it doesn't work anymore.

I have linked a jsfiddle project that is all of the code that goes with the button and the generator. If you see what I accidentally changed please let me know!

The JSFiddle link and the code with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/0tnp7km8/9/

```
<button id="test" onclick="testFunction()">
    Random Number
</button>

    <p id="randnum"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function testFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    document.getElementById("randnum").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: `a random number 1-50` ... `Math.random() * 10` - one of these things is not like the other

Answer (score 2):

JSFiddle will wrap it in a closure so your function isn't global. Change the Load type option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If JSFiddle is not working, try doing this:
[image: How to change load type of JS]

Algorithm-wise, here is what you must change: 
`Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1` only generates a random number from `1` to `10`. Try if this works according to your requirements:

```js
function testFunction() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
  document.getElementById("randnum").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button id="test" onclick="testFunction()">
    Random Number
</button>

<p id="randnum"></p>
```